# useContext or useEffect to load data in APP... which should be use?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I am programming an application.
When people are registering, they could choose a list of Institut before fill the form.

I am calling an API which give me the list of available Instituts.

In my RegisterForm, i will need to show the InstitutList... what is the most logical way to do that ?

=> Call in my registerForm component my API with useEffect ... and i call the API each time.

Or i STORE the list inside a useContext.

( i will have a Table, with list of Instituts, with Filters by name, country ..etc

So perhaps a Context could help me with filter ?

I am very confuse ... thank you to give me the best practices.

Comment: useEffect to load data

Comment: Thank you Anthony, and i use "Context" only if i need the list in other component during the same process?